# How can get PID of program execute SQL query show in V$SQL

Tags: oracle, pid

I could see recent SQL executed in V$SQL, but it not show the PID

Are there anyway to show it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can only find the PID if the SQL statement is still running and is attached to a session:

```
select v$sql.sql_id, v$process.pid
from v$sql
join v$session
    on v$sql.sql_id = v$session.sql_id
join v$process
    on v$session.paddr = v$process.addr;
```